# Может ли стать причиной утечки памяти объявление SharedPreferences и SQLiteDatabase статическими?

Tags: java, android, outofmemoryerror

Я обычно в небольших приложениях объявляю `SharedPreferences` статическим, и `SQLiteDatabase` статическим, может ли это стать причиной утечки памяти? Или мне лучше в каждом нужном классе/фрагменте объявлять `SharedPreferences` или `SQLiteDatabase`, проделывать нужные операции и закрывать их с выходом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Само объявление статичным экземпляры класса менеджера БД, или Shared, наоборот скорей всего избавит от лишних утечек, ну это если рассуждая что такое static. В целом дальше зависит от использования. Ликнуть Shared я даже не представляю как это возможно при static, а вот с БД действительно можно такое устроить причем как при записи, так и при чтении. Ну вот например если вы будете ставить курсор и не закрывать его, и то в это случае вы получите что-то типо `Object Sqlite.* was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.` Поэтому даже рассуждая так, можно сказать как в документации `SQLite will never leak memory. This is true even in the face of memory allocation failures or other system errors.` Вкратце в Sqlite нет мемори ликов, если вы даже сами накосячите. Но иногда можно встретить, такое

```
Leak found
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SQLiteDatabase created and never closed
```

Существует много подходов, как использовать БД Sqlite, но есть пару докладов, в которых рассказывается, что самый лучший способ для ANdroid это открыть при запуске (в Application классе) и закрывать при выходе. Иначе как бы вы не использовали коннекты к БД с разных конекстов, то ловите  `database is locked`, синглтоном но можете словить `attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase` поэтому я бы советовал не заниматься преждевременной оптимизацией БД, особенно в маленьких приложениях. Сам static ужасен для структуры проекта, в любом случае лучше не использовать его.

Comment: То есть объявлять `SharedPreferences` и `SQLiteDatabase` все таки это нормально, или нет? Я просто не совсем понял ваш ответ, точнее то, что вы говорите сначала `Само объявление статичным экземпляры класса менеджера БД, или Shared, наоборот скорей всего избавит от лишних утечек`, а потом, `Сам static ужасен для структуры проекта, в любом случае лучше не использовать его.`

Comment: сами стстик-преференсы может и не потекут, но они принимают контекст, а в "небольших приложениях" (что я понимаю синоним новичок) контекст принято брать от вызывающей активити, а не апликэйшена. в результате получаем удержание этой активити через ее контекст. Вообще строго не рекомендуется любые носители контекста  делать статическими, а если есть сильная необходимость - использовать контекст приложения (applicationContext), а не компонентов, как активити или вью. Думаю на это стоит обратить внимание в ответе (свой писать из за уточнения считаю лишним)

Comment: лучше не использовать статик. А ответ так звучит, чтоб дать понять что это не зло, а просто всё зависит от того, как вы используете это в текущем приложении, так как вы сказали что приложение небольшое.
@pavlofff да нет шаред никогда не будет держать контекст активити, он использeут ContextWrapper всегда, хотя теоретически то что вы говорите возможно но не с SharedPreferences.

Comment: Хотя если наплодить editor, да в теории можно так сделать, ну опять же, очень тяжело себе такое представить, да и IDE вроде как предупредит. Опять же статик не причем тут, это уже использование функций класса, немного не то.